Reference request about rational map using divisors
Given a smooth projective curve $C$ and a divisor $D$, we get a morphism $\varphi_D:C\to\mathbb{P}^n$ induced by $D$. Assume $n>0$, etc. Now, let $W_n$ be the variety of effective line bundles of degree $n$ on $C$; we can then define the rational map
$$\Psi:W_n\dashrightarrow(\mathbb{P}^{n})^*$$
that takes a divisor $F$ to $\mathrm{span}\{\varphi_D(F)\}$. When $D=K_C$ is the canonical divisor, then $\Psi$ can just be identified with the Gauss map of the theta divisor $\Theta$ on the Jacobian $JC$.
My question is the following: Other than the Gauss map, has this general construction of $\Psi$ been studied anywhere? I'm looking for some kind of reference or name for this construction. Thanks a lot!
